# Why made community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

One of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137785/why-are-variables-i-and-j-used-for-counters) was made yesterday community wiki, and I have no problem with that. I just wanted to know how one could find out why was it made. The only possible reason i found is that there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454303/why-are-we-using-i-as-a-counter-in-loops) to mine from a while back, It was an honest mistake i did not realize. Yet if that is the reason why is the other question not made CW and only mine was. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are automatically converted when they have more than 30 answers (among other conditions, but this is what applies to your case).